# Run migrations against the test database

Tags: python, django, migration

I do not want migrations to be run before each test round, that's why I run my tests with `--reusedb --nomigrations`

I still need to setup the database, once. For that I do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

How do I tell `migrate` to run in "test" mode, so that the right databases (with the `test_` are used)?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Django test runner setups separate database for test, which is derived from database in your `settings.py`. If you setup test database separately, test runner will use it.

If you still need to run some migrations in test database, you can run `migrate` command with `--database` option.

`python manage.py migrate --database test`

You can specify your target database in test case:

```py
class TestMyViews(TransactionTestCase):
    databases = {'default', 'other'}

    def test_index_page_view(self):
        call_some_test_code()
```

[migrate command documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

[testcase with database documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase)

Comment: It is a prefix, not a suffix: `test_something`. I do not want to be concerned with these details when running the `manage.py` command: I want django to do the right thing, that is, the same thing that it is already doing when running the unit tests. How do I tell `manage.py migrate` to do use the same database names that it would do when running tests? I have lots of databases, and manually calling manage.py for each one is too error prone.

Comment: [multi-db test case doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#multi-database-support). Quote: Django sets up a test database corresponding to every database that is defined in the DATABASES definition in your settings and referred to by at least one test through databases. If you specify --reusedb, it will check if db is not present, and if so, will run migrations, else it would just use it as-is. Also you can specify databases for each testcase, as in doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pytest --create-db` to [force re-creation of the test database](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#example-work-flow-with-reuse-db-and-create-db).